# App crashes on ValueChanged of UIDatePicker for UITextField in UIAlertController

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uitextfield, uidatepicker, uialertcontroller

I instantiate an UIAlertController and assign an UIDatePicker to one of its UITextField(s) as the input view. I also assigned a ValueChanged event handler to the picker. The UIDatePicker correctly shows when the mentioned UITextField gets focus, but when I change the value of the date the app crashes.

Please consider the code below.

```
var d = UIAlertController.Create( "Confirm", "Fill below with the required info.", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

d.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, ((UIAlertAction obj) => SubmitAction(obj, d))));
d.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null));

d.AddTextField((delegate(UITextField obj) {
    UIDatePicker picker = new UIDatePicker ();
    picker.ValueChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { obj.Text = picker.Date.Description; };
    obj.InputView = picker;
}));

PresentViewController(d, true, null);
```

Again, the picker shows up fine. The app crashes on the ValueChanged event even with an EMPTY handler `picker.ValueChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {};`.

No crashes without adding the event handler!

This code is in a button TouchUpInside event handler.

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have confused event methods in your code sample. `TouchUpInside` won't fire for the picker. If you want to update the text view's content if a new date value is selected, you will need to use:

```
picker.ValueChanged += (pickerSender, pickerArgs) =>
{
        obj.Text = picker.Date.Description;
};
```

To prevent this from crashing, you'll need to keep a reference to the UIDatePicker instance around, otherwise it will be collected too early. Easiest way is to move the date picker to class scope:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    this.btnTest.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;
}

UIDatePicker picker;

void HandleTouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var d = UIAlertController.Create( "Confirm", "Fill below with the required info.", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    d.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, ((UIAlertAction obj) => {})));
    d.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null));

    d.AddTextField((delegate(UITextField obj) {
        picker = new UIDatePicker ();
        picker.ValueChanged += (pickerSender, pickerArgs) =>
        {
            obj.Text = picker.Date.Description;
        };
        obj.InputView = picker;
    }));
    PresentViewController(d, true, null);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I totally messed up the post: the TouchUpInside was absolutely unwanted in THE ORIGINAL POST. The required event handler is the one specified in the title, ValueChanged. I updated it. However now I will try keeping a class scope reference as you suggested.

Comment: And that was absolutely it! Too early collection. Global reference did the trick! Thanks again!